# Given the percent rain coverage in an area, what is the probability of hitting rain after driving X distance?

Tags: probability, area

For simplicity's sake, I would say that the rain clouds are static. The question essentially becomes: *given a finite area filled with random shaded regions covering X% of the area, what is the probability that a random contiguous line Y units long will cross through any of the shaded regions?*

[image: Example, circle with shaded regions and a line, all distances and areas labeled]

If there's 50% coverage and you stay home, you've got a 50% chance of getting rained on. If you drive across every single inch of the area, then you've got a 100% chance of hitting rain. But if you drive over just 25% of the area...?

And that's another thing, when discussing it in terms of a car, it's more accurate to think of the area you cover by driving as exactly that -- area. *Not* a line. But I'm still not totally sure what to do in either case :P

I've thought about this literally for months, and the closest related problem I can find is calculating the probability of hitting a target on a dart board with a dart. But this problem is slightly different in that, instead of throwing a single point at the dart board, you're throwing an infinite series of points in a line. Or *not* a line if you're... driving in a car over the dart board...